# Map a php array to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array in php:

```
<?php

return array(
 'r'      => '16:9',
 'check'            => array(
                            array('w' => 640, 'q' => 70),
                            array('w' => 960, 'q' => 70)
                      ),                            
 'window_height'        => 800
);
```

I need to get this in my javascript, so I have:

```
<script>var config = "{{ json_encode(Config::get('conf')) }}";</script>
```

But im having trouble getting each element out.

Note: {{}} is laravel for echo.

Comment: "Note: {{}} is laravel for echo" -> Its **twig**, not laravel

Comment: Why don't you create a string variable in PHP (json encode stuff) and try echoing the variable alone in your template? Twig does a lot, but there's no reason to offloading everything to Twig

Comment: "getting each element out"... **HOW**? your json_encode isn't working? having trouble accessing the config array in JS?

Comment: Just suggesting but why don't you return a `json_encode`d version of the array? Something like `return json_encode($array)`.

Comment: So what problem are you actually having? `json_encode()` should convert your associative array to an object (with nested arrays in `check` property) as you desire.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there is no additional HTML escaping applied by your template engine, all you have to do is remove the quotes.  JSON-encoding takes care of all this for you.

```
<script>var config = {{ json_encode(Config::get('conf')) }};</script>
```

You can debug this yourself by viewing the raw output of your PHP script.  (Usually "view source" in your browser.)

Now, I don't know Twig, but [according to its documentation there may be a better way by using its own JS escaping](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/autoescape.html).  Untested obviously, but give this a try:

```
{% autoescape 'js' %}
    <script>var config = {{ Config::get('conf') }};</script>
{% endautoescape %}
```